# How to provide details about multiple operating systems?

Tags: xml, schema

I'm adding schema.org-data to my site. I'm looking at operating-system-details. According to this speccs: https://schema.org/operatingSystem, you can use values like

```
Windows 7, OSX 10.6, Android 1.6
```

I build a web app so it's supported on basically all desktop-Os:es that can run a modern browser. What value should I use? Can I use more than one value, in that case how should the markup look?

```
<meta itemprop="operatingSystem" content="Windows" />
<meta itemprop="operatingSystem" content="OS X" />
<meta itemprop="operatingSystem" content="Linux" />
```

or

```
<meta itemprop="operatingSystem" content="Windows, OS X, Linux" />
```

Comment: [Google Developers Test Tool](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool) accept both markups.